# Is it possible files get corrupted when downloading them via VPN?

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, browser, download, file-transfer

I know files can get corrupted during transfer, although rarely

but I wonder downloading via VPN will more likely corrupt files than without it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Less likely.

VPN adds an abstraction layer which provides another level of integrity and more flexibility (eg with some vpns like Openvpn endpoint IP addresses can change without a VPN loosing its connection) and the encryption/decryption routines greatly increase the likelyhood of detecting corrupt packets.

What can happen is it can slow down transfers depending on the location of the VPN and how it handles fragmentation (and VPN overhead)

Answer (score 0):

The VPN packets are encrypted, sent and decrypted at the other end.

So if the packet was corrupted, it would not decrypt and then be re-transmitted.

On the whole then VPN is less likely to corrupt than a regular session.

I find both to be quite reliable because regular TCP/IP transmissions error correct as well.